# NavigationUI.navigateUp does nothing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have an Activity, where I have a fragment, in which I have referenced a Navigation Graph component:

activity XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_fragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Navigation graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_fragment"
    app:startDestination="@id/countryPickerFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/countryPickerFragment"
        android:name="me.sparker0i.ottcontent.view.composer.countrypicker.CountryPickerFragment"
        android:label="Pick a Country"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_country_picker">
        <action android:id="@+id/countryPickerFragmentToPlatformPickerFragment"
            app:destination="@+id/platformPickerFragment">
            <argument
                android:name="countryValue"
                app:argType="string" />
        </action>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/platformPickerFragment"
        android:name="me.sparker0i.ottcontent.view.composer.platformpicker.PlatformPickerFragment"
        android:label="Pick a Platform"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_platform_picker">
        <argument
            android:name="countryValue"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Activity Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, null)
    }
}
```

In the first fragment that opens up (`CountryPickerFragment`), I have code which observes a value from a `MutableLiveData` inside a `ViewModel`. When the value is observed, it opens up the 2nd fragment, navigated using the Navigation Library. The relevant code for the `CountryPickerFragment` is below:

```
class CountryPickerFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware, CoroutineScope {
    override val kodein by closestKodein()

    private lateinit var job: Job

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        job = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }

    private var mutableCountries = MutableLiveData<List<Country>>()

    private val viewModelFactory: ContentViewModelFactory by instance()
    private lateinit var viewModel: ContentViewModel
    private lateinit var selectionTracker: SelectionTracker<Long?>

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_country_picker, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(ContentViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.countryValue.observeForever{value ->
            val action = CountryPickerFragmentDirections.countryPickerFragmentToPlatformPickerFragment(value)
            requireView().findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the second fragment as well:

```
class PlatformPickerFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware, CoroutineScope {
    override val kodein by closestKodein()

    private lateinit var job: Job

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        job = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }

    val args: PlatformPickerFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    private val viewModelFactory: ContentViewModelFactory by instance()
    private lateinit var viewModel: ContentViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_platform_picker, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(ContentViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val countryValue = args.countryValue
        Log.i("Country Value", countryValue)
    }
}
```

While this piece of code does open up the Second fragment within the same activity and also shows up the `Country Value` inside Logcat, it also brings a Back button on the Action Bar. When I try to press that back button, it does not go back to the previous fragment, instead it puts up yet another `Country Value` inside the Logcat. Pressing the back button on the phone's navigation bar also does the same.

How do I go back to the previous fragment (`CountryPickerFragment`) from the newly spawned fragment (`PlatformPickerFragment`)?

PS. If anyone wants to have a look at the code, you may go [here](https://github.com/Sparker0i/ott-content-app)

Comment: Went through your code. I think the navigation works correctly, the issue is with how you observe your liveData. Try debugging your app with a breakpoint on line 62 in your `CountryPickerFragment`, you will see that every time you hit "navigate up" from `PlatformPickerFragment`,  the code on line 62 is executed, meaning the navigation does try to bring you back to `CountryPickerFragment`, but as soon as it does that, the fragment's liveData fire up, including the logic to bring you again to the `PlatformPickerFragment`. It happens fast, that's why it seems like the back button does nothing.

Comment: As a side note, you should never be using `observeForever` in a Fragment - use `observe(viewLifecycleOwner)` when observing from `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: @DatPhamTat thanks for that. Yeah I do notice that it does try to come back to the `CountryPickerFragment`. As a side note, I did try to use `observe` instead of `observeForever` inside my Fragment as suggested by @ianhanniballake, sadly that didn't work either. It is showing same behaviour

Comment: Cant add answer as someone closed the issue. I did come up with a temporary fix:

 === 

viewModel.countryValue.removeObservers(this@CountryPickerFragment.viewLifecycleOwner)
        viewModel.countryValue.observe(this@CountryPickerFragment.viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {value ->
            if (value != null) {
                // navigate to PlatformPickerFragment
                viewModel.countryValue.postValue(null)
            }
        })
 === 

It worked for me, try to understand the logic yourself. In general though, you should try to remove all the `observeForever`s.

Comment: PS. Change from `observeForever` to `observer` did nothing. I had to modify my viewModel value to become nullable. That fixed my problem.